# Flutter getting headers with module interfaces is unsupported error on MacOs

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, dart

Newly i received `macos` and i'm trying to run `flutter` project on that after installing some dependencies, my `flutter` project developed on `windows` and when i try to run that on `silumator` i get this error, i try to remove `ios` folder before and run this command into project folder:

```bash
flutter create .
```

Error log:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Error (Xcode): no such module '__ObjC'
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dykfzfnvttucudfjiighobctenhj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.private.swiftinterface:9:18

Error (Xcode): failed to verify module interface of 'Runner' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dykfzfnvttucudfjiighobctenhj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.private.swiftinterface:0:0

Error (Xcode): no such module '__ObjC'
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dykfzfnvttucudfjiighobctenhj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.swiftinterface:9:18

Error (Xcode): failed to verify module interface of 'Runner' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dykfzfnvttucudfjiighobctenhj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner.swiftinterface:0:0

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
```

Screenshot 1:
[image]

Screenshot 2:
[image]

```swift
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

#
#
#
#
#

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

installing `pod`s:

```bash
➜  ios pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 17 dependencies from the Podfile and 21 total pods installed.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

[!] The `Runner [Debug]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Runner [Release]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Runner [Profile]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```